# Send message to user upon join with discord.py self-bot

Tags: discord, discord.py

It suppose to send message upon join but Member_join event isn't working
By the way it's a self bot
Discord.py Version : 1.7.3
My code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  await member.send("welcome to random server")
  print(f"Sent message to {member.username}")
```

Comment: By the way It's a self bot :

Comment: Self bot are against the TOS of discord, please see this article: [support/discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots). Most people will not help because of this.

Comment: I know but I wanna try

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you use [discord.py-self](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py-self/) then your current code will work. it in newer version  as in newer version of discord.py they have blocked the access to api thru non bot auth token.